# Creating Angular Element Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, static

I have an angular page that displays a list of items. It iterates over the list and displays it in a div. Here's the HTML code for that:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-title-section">
        <h1>{{item.text}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item-special-section" 
            ng-show="item.type == 'FooB' ||
                    item.type == 'FooC' ||
                    item.type == 'FooD'">
        <div>
            <h2>Speical</h2>
            <p>Type Section</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>{{item.text}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `item-title-section` always shows. But I only want the `item-special-section` to show if the current item is of type B, C, or D. The problem here is if the list contains all 3 items I just want the div to be printed once but the text of each item printed. So in this case:

```
{
    {
        type: FooA,
        title: FooA,
        text: "Some text for this element"
    },
    {
        type: FooB,
        title: FooB,
        text: "Some text for this element"
    },
    {
        type: FooC,
        title: FooC,
        text: "Some text for this element"
    }
}
```

The `item-special-section` div prints twice. Is there a way in angular to statically create an html element, meaning *if* it's created create it only once?

Comment: what is an current item?

Answer (score 0):

So one workaround I have figured out for your problem is to allocate the logic for showing only one special item to a separate function attached to the `$scope`. I have created a [Plnkr Example](https://embed.plnkr.co/kwHJTLeXwuAZS3omqjzB/) to help demonstrate my explanation.

**HTML**

```
<div class="item-special-section"
     ng-show="showSpecialSection(item.type)">
  <p>I'm a special case!</p>
  <p>{{item.text}}</p>
</div>
```

In the HTML we only allow that element to show if `showSpecialSection` returns `true` and we pass in the `item.type`.

**JavaScript**

```
// Define out specialItems
$scope.specialItems   = ['FooB', 'FooC', 'FooE'];

// Create an array to stash the first item that fulfills
// the requirement in showSpecialSection
$scope.allowedItem    = [];

$scope.showSpecialSection = function(item) {
  // First we check if the item is in our defined list
  // of special items
  if ($scope.specialItems.indexOf(item) != -1) {

    // Next depending on if allowedItem has anything,
    // we either add it to allowedItem or check if it is
    // already inside allowedItem
    if ($scope.allowedItem.length == 0) {
      $scope.allowedItem.push(item);
      return true;
    }
    else if ($scope.allowedItem.indexOf(item) != -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  // return false if all other logic checks failed
  return false;
}
```

Please let me know if this works out for you, and comment if you have questions. Cheers ~